# Swift Playgrounds for iPad - GameCenter Entitlement

Tags: swift, ipad, game-center, swift-playground

The GameCenter entitlement isn’t present in the list of capabilities for iPad playgrounds. Does anyone know if it is possible to add it programmatically?  Has anyone had success in doing so, if so, how?